# Python: Classes, Methods, Parameter Attributes

Tags: python, class

I am rather new to using classes. I struggle with functions (i.e. methods) in classes and how to access the classes attributes via method parameter.

My aim is to have a method accessing an instance's list (and the instances contained therein, yadda yadda)

While:

```
class dictclasser:
    def __init__(self, attribute):
        self.attribute = attribute

    def printattr(self):
        self.printattr2()

    def printattr2(self):
        return self.attribute


classcollection = [] 

while True:
    attribute = input()
    classcollection.append(dictclasser(attribute))
    for i in classcollection:
        print(i.printattr())
```

Returns None

```
class dictclasser:
    def __init__(self, attribute):
        self.attribute = attribute

    def printattr(self):
        return self.attribute




classcollection = [] 

while True:
    attribute = input()
    classcollection.append(dictclasser(attribute))
    for i in classcollection:
        print(i.printattr())
```

Returns everything as intended. I cannot figure out why printattr can access the instances attribute and printattr2 cannot. I have checked "Similar Question" to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Because you missed a return statement in the first `printattr`. In order to propagate the return value of `printattr2` onwards from `printattr` you have to *return the returned value*:

```
def printattr(self):
    return self.printattr2()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your printattr function has no return statement. Change

```
self.printattr2()
```

to

```
return self.printattr2()
```